# Fixed window for certain part of page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm wondering how I can make a fixed window on the side of a form like on the Apple page. (http://store.apple.com/us/buy-mac/macbook-air?product=MD711LL/B&step=config)

I tried `position:fixed;` and all the 'easy' solutions, but they don't work.

Comment: Well, I tried `position: fixed` and `position: absolute`, however, they work, but not like on the apple page. The div is supposed to be fixed only for a certain part of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did this same thing for a client recently.

Best way is using jQuery. I used this [jQuery sticky script](http://stickyjs.com) with the following code on the page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    if (!!$('.sticky').offset()) { // make sure ".sticky" element exists

    $("#filter_sidebar").sticky({topSpacing:50});

    }

});
</script>
```

Modify as needed and you may need to tweak `topSpacing` to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm. Is it possible to change the vertical alignment as well? It jumps to the left every time now.

Comment: The value of topSpacing will adjust the vertical alignment.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant horizontal alignment ;p

Comment: I wrapped mine in a containing div, then applied some CSS to that one to space it left or right (ie. margin-left: 40px;).

Comment: Is it possible to unstick at a certain point as well with this library?

Comment: There's an `.unstick()` method you can read about here: https://github.com/garand/sticky#usage